# How to extract a data point from multiple csv files using R

Tags: r

I have a very big data frame and multiple copies of it that I programmed R to read automatically. I am now trying figure a way to read the data points automatically as well.

I previously had the code written as the following when it was reading a single csv file that I named "mydata":

```
subject_variable = mydata$X0[1]

size_variable = mydata$X29[1]

vertical_movement = 
  if (mydata$X37[1] == 0) 
  {
    "None"
  }else{
    "Moving"
  } 
horizontal_start= mydata$X36[1]
```

Instead of a single data file, I currently have a list of data files. How would the code I wrote above would change so it would read the list of data files that I have?

Would I have to use a for loop for each variable? or would it work with just one for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely`mydata` is a data frame or something similar, not a CSV file(name)? What do you have; a list of data frames or a list of filenames?

Comment: it's a list of data frames

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems like `mydata` is a dataframe, so as long as you have a list of dataframes, the following approach will work well:

```
#create a function with the process you've already done for one of the dataframes
fn <- function(mydata){
subject_variable = mydata$X0[1]

size_variable = mydata$X29[1]

vertical_movement = 
  if (mydata$X37[1] == 0) 
  {
    "None"
  }else{
    "Moving"
  } 
horizontal_start= mydata$X36[1]
}


#do that for all the dataframes
lapply(fn, list_of_dataframes)
```

If you have a list of file locations, you can also use `lapply` along with `read_csv` (or similar) to create a list of dataframes and use the above approach.

Comment: But how do I define these variables in terms of the data frame list? because my code will not have "mydata" it will only have the list "data_list".